# haskell Instance of Fractional Int required for definition of average

Tags: haskell

i got this error while writing my average function which is as follow

```
module Assignment where

average xs = sum xs / length xs
```

what does it actually want?
is it asking for definition ? I provided that too but same error occured

Comment: No, the problem is that you can not simply use `/` on integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have given a definition so that is not the problem. The problem is that Haskell can not apply the `/` operator on two `Int`s, indeed:

```
Prelude> (2 :: Int) / 3

<interactive>:1:1: error:
    • No instance for (Fractional Int) arising from a use of ‘/’
    • In the expression: (2 :: Int) / 3
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = (2 :: Int) / 3
```

Here in the terminal we want to divide `2` with `3`. We force Haskell to use an `Int` for the `2`, and it complains about the same thing.

The reason is that `(/)` is defined in `Fractional`:

```
class Num a => Fractional a where
  (/) :: a -> a -> a
  recip :: a -> a
  fromRational :: Rational -> a
  {-# MINIMAL fromRational, (recip | (/)) #-}
```

as you can see, the definition states that all `Fractional`s are `Num`s, but not all `Num`s are `Fractional`s. That is logical. Notice the signature of `(/) :: a -> a -> a`. If we would use that on `Int`s, it would have signature `(/) :: Int -> Int -> Int`. But that would mean that `2/3` would be `0` or `1` (given we take the closest results). Buth are quite off. Since people would make a lot of errors with this, the designers of the Haskell library decided *not* to make `Int` a `Fractional`, but offered a `div` function for *integral* division.

Of course this is not helping us much. Since we probably do not want the result to be an `Int` in the first place. So what we can do is *convert* the `length` result to a `Fractional`. We can do this for instance with the [**`fromIntegral :: (Integral a, Num b) => a -> b`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fromIntegral) function. So we can then redefine the function as:

```
average :: Fractional a => [a] -> a
average xs = sum xs / fromIntegral (length xs)
```

Note that here the type of the *elements* of the list decide what the type of the output of average will be. That type needs to be `Fractional` as well. So we can not process a list of `Int`s, unless we thus first preprocess the list (for instance calling `fromIntegral` to the elements of the list). In case the list contains integral elements, we can first calculate the sum, and then convert it to a `Fractional` (since then the result will be more precise). We can then define it like:

```
integrals_average :: (Integral a, Fractional b) => [a] -> b
integrals_average xs = fromIntegral (sum xs) / fromIntegral (length xs)
```